# When will the latest released of Firefox, Thunderbird and Clamav be available in the repository

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

RE:  Firefox - v46.0.1 released 5-3-16 - currently running v46.0
     Thunderbird - v45.1.0 released 5-10-16 - currently running v38.7.2
     Clamav - v0.99.2 released 5-3.16 - currently running v0.98.7

When will these new releases be made available in the repository/ies?

Answer (score 0):

The newest versions are available in this repository  `ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa`

> Users of the most recent Ubuntu release can get new versions of Firefox a few days early from the semi-official ubuntu-mozilla-security archive. This archive holds updates to the Mozilla suite (including Firefox) while they're tested for security and stability.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion

Comment: I'm not certain as to use a "daily build" (beta) release ppa.   I realize that the "powers that are" do checks on new releases before releasing/adding them to the respective repository/ies.  I have Ubuntu Unity 14.04.x and Mint Mate 17.3 right now.  My main concern is that  how are we end users supposed to maintain the apps we have as "up to date" when nothing is released?  Please understand that I am not wanting to "dis" anyone but this is getting a bit old.  I would, if I knew how, manually install these  and others.  But I am not familiar with the ins and outs of using the terminal.